# Linux command How to delete all with .html extension

Tags: linux, command, putty

i am using putty, want to delete all files which having .html extension

I am trying the below ways

1st get the file by using find command

```
find . -name "*.html" -type f
```

Listing all files having .html extension

now i am going to delete those files

```
find . -name "*.html" -type f -delete
```

OR

```
find . -name "*.html" -type f -exec rm {} +
```

both are not working for me, anybody know solution

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you're deleting the right files first!

```
 find . -name "*.html" -type f
```

To delete regardless of permissions...

```
sudo find . -name "*.html" -type f -delete
```

Comment: I tested it and it works. Is it possible that the files are being recreated after you delete them? You can check the date modified with `ls -l *.html` or `stat *.html`.

Comment: the above command will delete all files form all directories. how can i delete files only from current directory?

Answer (score 1):

just go to that directory and type this command

```
ls *.html
```

this will list all the html files. this is to make sure you want to delete all these files
then run the following command

```
rm -f *.html
```

it will delete all files in that directory ending with .html